# NSRegularExpression not getting exact text

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4.5

I have a string like:

```
<book>MyBook</book><value>myValue</value>
```

Now I want to get the text "myValue" out of this string. I want to use NSRegularExpression to do this. I tried this:

```
 NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<book>MyBook</book>\\s*<value>).*?(</value>)"
                                                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                            error:&error];
    NSArray *textArray = [regex matchesInString:myData options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [myData length])];

    NSTextCheckingResult * result = [rege firstMatchInString:myData
                                                           options:0
                                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [myData length])];
```

The result is:

```
<book>MyBook</book><value>myValue</value>
```

So I get the whole string, but I only want "myValue". How can I do this? What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have a string like: `<book>MyBook</book><value>myValue</value>`" - so you are switching to `NSXMLParser`. ***Now.***

Comment: Yes, actually it's an XML, but I've read that the problem with NSXMLParser is that if there is 1 error in the XML it will fail, so therefor I want to use regex to be sure to read the content.

Comment: You want to make sure to read malformed content? At least NSXMLParser can create error messages. The reason why it is so a bad idea to use regular expressions for parsing XML/HTML is that it is impossible. You cannot write a fully fledged XML parser with regular expressions because XML can express stuff that you cannot express with regular expressions. Computer science 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because you wrote a regex that matches the entire string. I'd reckon that writing a regex that will only match the myValue part of the string is way too complicated to be bothered with (due to the fact that you've got MyBook string that will probably match anything myValue does).

I'd recommend not using regex for this, as they are not intended for the use you've described here. If you don't want to use any XML deserialization, you could use a `NSScanner` or any of the `NSString` class methods which will yield a simpler, and easier code to maintain.

For example, using an NSScanner and a few other methods:

```
NSString *stringToBeScanned = @"<book>MyBook</book><value>myValue</value>";
NSString *myValue;

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringToBeScanned];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"<value>" intoString:nil];
// After the above, we've got "<value>myValue</value>" left to scan

[scanner scanUpToString:@"</value>" intoString:&myValue];
// We ended up with a "<value>myValue" type of a string

// This will trim the remaining of the string we don't need
myValue = [myValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<value>" withString:@""];
```

The above could probably be written better and I might have made a mistake or two writing it out my head, but the principle should work.

Comment: Thx! I was thinking about this but maybe it's indeed better then using regex.. I've used this now and it works. Thx again!